# Q.all() promises not resolving deferred promises correctly

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am calling a POST multiple times in order to create objects on a server. The POST is wrapped in a promise. I create an array of promises and pass it to Q.all but when it is resolved all the objects in the array have the same id and only one object is created on the server.

Here's my code

```
for (var i = txArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {                
  txArray[i]._action = 'update';
  promises.push(newVertex(url));
};
return Q.all(promises).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});

function newVertex(url) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var xhr;

    try {
        xhr = new_xhr();
    } catch (e) {
        deferred.reject(-1);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                deferred.resolve(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(xhr);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The result returns objects all with the same id. Not sure why? Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Just figured out that if I pass false to xhr.open('POST', url, false); it works. Why? and can I leave it like that?

Comment: This code looks good. Can it be a race condition in your server?

Comment: @barcrab the only reason it works is because you are turning async off which wouldn't let anything happen until one finishes. It is not good to leave it this way. It "seems" to work but its not the promises that are working. Its just that you aren't doing them asynchronously.

Comment: Add a `console.log(xhr.responseText)` as soon as possible and you should find that it's actually the server that's faulty.  It's nothing to do with the promise code.

Comment: I seccond @ForbesLindesay, this code looks correct, the problem is with the server. Adding `false` is a bad idea as it will lock up the UI while the request completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue. The POST had a header with Content-Type:application/json. The server was therefore expecting some data to be passed to it. Passing some json data or even '{}' resolved the issue.

For example:

```
xhr.send('{}');
```

Thanks for every bodies feedback, it all helps.

Answer (score -1):

If everything works fine with `xhr.open('POST', url, false)`, then is would appear the sever doesn't handle multiple simultaneous requests properly. With async off, the requests are effectively forced to be handled sequentially.

The ideal solution would probably be to fix things at the server, however is **may** be acceptable to apply a better client-side "sequentializer" fix.

The code follows a fairly familiar pattern :

```
var promise = Q.defer().resolve().promise;//A ready-resolved seed promise.

//Now, instead of pushing promises onto an array, progressively build a .then() chain.
for (var i = txArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {                
    txArray[i]._action = 'update';
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return newVertex(url);
    });
};

//And add a terminal .then() to do whatever on completion of the sequence.
promise.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This allows `xhr.open('POST', url, true);` to be used in `newVertex()` (ie asynchronous requests).

I'm not too sure about the last `.then()`. You may need to play with it some.

### Footnote

This fix ensures that each user's requests are sequential. However, the bug at the server will remain. Only by fixing whatever is wrong at the server will you ensure that concurrent requests from two or more users do not give the problem; namely that duplicate ids can be issued. This will not necessarily occur during testing and could be a latent bug that does not manifest itself until some time in the future, when two users access this particular resource concurrently.

Therefore, the above fix is only appropriate if only **one** user can access the resource (and potentially, similar resources) concurrently. To be safe, you would need to take measures at the server to ensure that multiple concurrent access to the resource(s) cannot occur. It is almost undoubtedly easier to fix the actual bug - ie to ensure that the same id cannot be issued more than once.

I therefore reiterate that the above solution only **may** be acceptable.

Comment: This will almost certainly fail as soon as the website has 2 or more concurrent users though.  Plus it may be significantly slower.

Comment: Yes on both points though we don't know the application will have concurrent users, and "significantly slower" may still be "acceptably fast". And by the way, these issues are amongst those behind my "may be acceptable" proviso.

Comment: @ForbesLindesay I understand how this may impact performance but I'm not sure why 2 or more concurrent users will make it fail. Are you able to elaborate? Thanks

Comment: I have added a footnote to qualify the proviso that this fix only **may** be acceptable.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for your clarification. Your answer has enhanced my understanding of Promises, although the solution you suggest won't meet my needs and therefore need to figure out how I fix the server.

Comment: Hi Barcrab, post another question if necessary with a link here. I can't guarantee I'll be able to answer but will certainly take a look. Be sure to tag the question with whatever server-side technology(s) you are using, eg PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Despite my best efforts to qualify this answer with a heavy proviso, it has started to attract downvotes. Barcrab, please grab what you can from it before I'm forced to delete. Pesky downvoters!